# Modify all the image src values from jpg to png using jquery

Tags: jquery

The dom consists of the img attribute like

```
<img src="http://example.com/cat.jpg"
<img src="http://example.com/dog.jpg"
<img src="http://example.com/rat.jpg"
```

How to convert all the src values to png format like

```
<img src="http://example.com/cat.png"
<img src="http://example.com/dog.png"
<img src="http://example.com/rat.png"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop on your image and replace .jpg by .png

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each(function(){
   var src=$(this).attr("src").replace(".jpg",".png");
  $(this).prop("src",src);
 });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gg3dLd2c/)

Answer (score 0):

Your view

Add new class to all elements

```
<img class="old_image" src="http://example.com/cat.jpg">
<img class="old_image" src="http://example.com/dog.jpg">
<img class="old_image" src="http://example.com/rat.jpg">
```

Your Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".old_image").each(function(index){
      var src = $(this).attr("src").split('.'); // split src to array by "."
      src[src.length - 1] = 'png'; // change last element of array to png
      newSrc = src.join(".");   // join the array with "."
      $(this).attr("src",newSrc); // change the src attribute to new one.
   })
});
```